# @PersistenceContext EntityManager (JPA)

Tags: java, database, jpa, glassfish, ejb

I am creating a Java EE application using JPA and EJB. The problem in @PersistenceContext(unitName = "airline") when i comment this line it give me error null_pointer_exception and when put it getting the following error when the code is run on server.

```
Severe:   Exception while preparing the app : Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [com.airline.service.Test2EJBService/entityManager] in the scope of the module called [Test2]. Please verify your application.
```

my classes :

AddPassenger2

```
@WebServlet(name = "AddPassenger2", urlPatterns = {"/AddPassenger2"})
public class AddPassenger2 extends HttpServlet {


    @EJB
    Test2EJBService bService;


   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet AddPassenger</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h4> Hello Every body in Test2 :) <h4>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

        Passenger passenger = new Passenger();

        passenger.setFirstName("Loai");
        passenger.setLastName("Amr");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1996);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
        Date dob = cal.getTime();

        passenger.setDob(dob);
        passenger.setGender(Gender.Male);
        passenger.setFlightClass(FlightClass.Couch);     

        bService.addPassenger(passenger);

        System.out.println("First name : " + passenger.getFirstName());

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

my EJB container :

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Test2EJBService {

//    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "Test2PU")
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "airline")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void addPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
//        EntityManager createEntityManager;
//        createEntityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Test2PU").createEntityMana‌ger();
        entityManager.persist(passenger);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

and persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Test2PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/airline</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IWCA.png)

can any body help i spend 3 days in the same error and can't solve it.

and here our connection with my database :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA1qA.png)

Comment: A similar error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167619/fixing-could-not-resolve-a-persistence-unit-errors-when-pu-is-specified-fo

Comment: can't do that because it give me exception : java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Your `persistence-unit-name` in the `persistence.xml` file still says "Test2PU" instead of "airline". Verify that. Also, do make sure your connection pool and JDBC resource are properly configured on the server with the same name (i.e. airline)

Comment: i make sure for the connection can you review the pic in the post i make edit for it .

Comment: The pic doesn't quite say what I mean. I expect the connection pool and JDBC Resource configurations to be on your glassfish server, not netbeans or your source code

Comment: And if you insist on using "Test2PU" as your persistence-unit-name, then you should have @PersistenceContext(unitName="Test2PU") instead of @PersistenceContext(unitName="airline").

Comment: can you help me how i make sure the connection establish between glassfish and pool and JDBC resource ??

Comment: can you see the second pic i edited in the question the glassfish said (Ping succeded) . is that what you mean ?

Comment: i made @PersistenceContext(unitName="Test2PU") and give me another exception it can also when i comment that and make entity manager factory : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError .

Comment: Good. Your connection pool works, but what remains now is the JDBC Resource. take care when you create one, the JNDI name should be the same as the one indicated on your persistence.xml file i.e. jdbc/airline