# How to deploy EJB and War modules at same time in NetBeans 8.2 and GlassFish 4.1.1

Tags: ejb, netbeans-8, glassfish-4

I have a problem to deploy EJB and WAR modules at the same time in NetBeans 8.2 on GlassFish 4.1.1. The following message is shown:

```
[[ Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [ejb.NewMessage/em] in the scope of the module called [TestEJB-ejb]. Please verify your application.. Please see server.log for more details.]]
```

When I checked server.log file of GlassFish server, I faced with the following erreor message:

```
[2018-07-28T12:59:45.406+0430] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=427 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1532766585406] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while preparing the app : Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [ejb.NewEntityFacade/em] in the scope of the module called [TestEJB-ejb]. Please verify your application.]]
```

Is there any solution for that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered packaging them together in an EAR? And you know that nowadays you can put most code in the WAR (look up EJB Lite) so chances are you do not even have to split up your code?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167619/fixing-could-not-resolve-a-persistence-unit-errors-when-pu-is-specified-fo .

Comment: @fvu Thanks for replay. Yes I did. I create an enterprise application which was included both EJB and WAR Modules

Comment: @fvu Even I created an independent EJB Module but it is not  deployed

Comment: With what you provide it's impossible to really pinpoint the issue, but could it be that you have issues related to where you put the persistence.xml file? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073635/sharing-a-persistence-unit-across-components-in-a-ear-file) goes into detail about where you could put it in order to make it accessible

Comment: @fvu No it is not because I follow the solution which is presented in this movie

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qk4qYQG5tvM

But is not also worked for me.

Comment: That's ejb3, I'd strongly suggest you look for an ejb3.1 tutorial as that is what GF4 implements. It does away with lots of the odd stuff in the ee spec, among other things you will almost certainly package your app in just 1 war, doing away with an extra layer of confusion you're facing now. At the same time you may want to have a look at [Payara](https://payara.fish), a greatly improved version of Glassfish. They stopped releasing the 4 series for free, the last versions (that are still far ahead of your current 4.1.1) can be found [here](https://www.payara.fish/previous_releases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not start to create your app or if you did not choose your programming framework, you can switch to Java Spring with less headache!

Read the first paragraph of the following link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework